# Exibir dado em tempo real

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Estou tentando exibir um dado retirado diretamente de meu banco de dados com esse *script*:

```
<script>
         setInterval( function contaUser(){
              document.write,("<?php
                   $sql = "SELECT Count(id) as c FROM tb_usuario";
                   $result = $con->query($sql);
                   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                    echo $row['c'].' Usuários';
               ?>");
               },2000 );
 </script>
```

Já inclui no início do arquivo todos os dados de conexão e etc... Gostaria de exibir esses dados em uma div, estilo "card"... Saberiam me dizer o que está errado?

Comment: Você já ouviu falar de linguagens do lado do servidor e do lado do cliente? Por exemplo, PHP atuará no lado do servidor, enquanto JavaScript, neste caso, atuará no lado do cliente. O **único** jeito deles se comunicarem é por HTTP. Pesquise sobre isso, pois parece que ainda lhe falta alguns conceitos **básicos** e **necessários**.

Comment: Amigo, você não vai conseguir rodar um código php dentro de um escopo javscript. 
O que você pode fazer é enviar um ajax com os dados pro servidor php, fazer a consulta, e exportar os dados de volta pro javascript. Ai então você faz o setInterval e atualiza de x em x tempos.

Comment: Siga isto: https://aiocollective.com/blog/auto-refresh-content-after-changes-in-database-ajax/

Comment: Tudo bem, muito obrigado!

Comment: div `estilo "card"...` como assim?

Comment: Bem-vindo Erick Figueiredo, não deixe de ler esses posts para poder obter boas respostas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Uma boa pratica será aceitar uma resposta que porventura tenha resolvido seu problema. Veja como em  https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No javascript chame via ajax a página PHP que executa o SELECT e retorna o resultado pretendido mostrando-o na `<div id="qqId"></div>`.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="qqId"></div>
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var tempo = 2000; //Dois segundos

    (function selectNumUsuarios () {
        $.ajax({
          url: "selectNumUsuarios.php",
          success: function (n) {
              //essa é a function success, será executada se a requisição obtiver exito
              $("#qqId").text(n);
          },
          complete: function () {
              setTimeout(selectNumUsuarios, tempo);
          }
       });
    })();
});


</script>
```

**selectNumUsuarios.php**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "Nome_DB");

/* checa conexão */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conexão falhou: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM cadastro")) {

    /* determina o número de linhas retornadas */
    $numUsuarios = $result->num_rows;

    printf($numUsuarios." Usuarios");

    $result->close();
}

/* fecha a conexão */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Caro Leo, setInterval vai executar deliberadamente, seria melhor setTimeout, que "deve" ser configurado para ser executado quando terminar a requisição XmlHttpRequest

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, bem lembrado, mas não sei qual a intenção do AP, resolvi então colocar uma OBS a respeito.

Comment: Caro Leo, não é questão de intenção do AP, setInterval com requisições assincronas do qual você não tem ideia de quando vai responder pode ocasionar um efeito colateral terrivel, pois o setInterval não esperada nada, o problema esta no seu código proposto.

Comment: O que o guilherme está tentando dizer é: Ao invés de fazer um setInterval pra rodar o ajax, coloque um setTimeout dentro do escopo do sucess dentro do ajax. Assim ele só vai chamar novamente quando a primeira requisição estiver completa e funcional. Caso contrário, pode acabar mandando outra requisição enquanto uma ainda está ocorrendo, que pode se resumir numa grande quantidade de problemas.

Comment: Valeu GuilhermeNascimento e @Máttheus Spoo, resposta editada.